# def lastLetters(words) eof error coming from outside of my code

Tags: python-3.x, string, slice

I'm supposed to make a function that takes the last two letters from an input and print an output that shows just the last two letters but reversed with a space in the middle I did this successfully in one environment but its giving me an eof error on the hackerrank platform from outside of my manipulable space

```
    def my_func():
        words = input()
        a = words
        print(a[-1],a[-2])

    my_func()
```

im supposed to take the input example "hello" and the output would be "o l"
this works on my phone where I first wrote it but is giving an eof error from a line in the pre wrote code on the hackerrank platform

Comment: Is it mentioned where the inputs will come from? I remember that some exercises already have pre-included code that sets how the script/function will run and get inputs.

Comment: the input comes from stdin and the line that generates the eof error is word = input()

Comment: No i haven't but I'm also not sure exactly what you mean or how to implement

Comment: What's the name of this challenge on HackerRank?

Comment: Last letters I think I no longer have access to it my time ran out but I am going to try to redo it so I'm still looking for a answer